# How to set checked with Radio.Group Antd?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have dynamic data that radio draw.

There is an id of an active radio, which also comes dynamically.

How to compare id and install cheked with Radio.Group.
And in the end I need to get the radio values in the form
This code does not work correctly.

dynamiclyData could be much bigger

```
const dynamiclyData = [
  { id: 1, value: "A" },
  { id: 2, value: "B" },
  { id: 3, value: "C" },
  { id: 4, value: "D" }
];

const idChekedFromRequest = 2;

const App = () => (
  <Form onFinish={val => console.log("val", val)}>
    <Form.Item name="radio">
      <Radio.Group name="radiogroup">
        {dynamiclyData.map(({ value, id }) => {
          return (
            <Radio key={id} checked={id === idChekedFromRequest}>
              {value}
            </Radio>
          );
        })}
      </Radio.Group>
      <Button htmlType="submit">submit</Button>
    </Form.Item>
  </Form>
);
```

[CodeSanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-night-cvusm?file=/index.js:0-819)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import React,{useState} from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Radio, Form, Button } from "antd";

const dynamiclyData = [
  { id: 1, value: "A" },
  { id: 2, value: "B" },
  { id: 3, value: "C" },
  { id: 4, value: "D" }
];

const App = () => {
  const [idChekedFromRequest,setIdChekedFromRequest] = useState(2);
  return (
  <Form onFinish={val => console.log("val", val)}>
    <Form.Item name="radio">
      {/* <Radio.Group name="radiogroup"> */}
      {dynamiclyData.map(({value, id}) => {
        return (
          <Radio key={id} onChange={()=>setIdChekedFromRequest(id)} checked={id===idChekedFromRequest}>
            {value}
          </Radio>
        );
      })}
      {/* </Radio.Group> */}
      <Button htmlType="submit">submit</Button>
    </Form.Item>
  </Form>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Comment: This answer helped me. But it's better if you could explain what you did here.

Comment: They removed the controlled Radio.Group and are controlling the Radios via state inside the app component.