# Need to do Radio button in antd default checked

Tags: reactjs, next.js, antd

I have a Radio Button Group with dynamically data coming from an array.
Here's the code :

```
<Radio.Group
    options={uniqueRadioElements}
    onChange={onCategorySelect}
    value={selectedCategory}
    optionType="button"
    buttonStyle="solid"
    className="select-category"
    checked="true"
/>
<Col span={24}>
    <div className="professionals-wrapper">
        {arrayOfElements
            .filter((item) => item.category === selectedCategory)
            .map((item) => {
                return (
                    <div className="details-of-categories">
                        <Image
                            src="/images/clinic.png"
                            preview={false}
                            alt="photo 4"
                        />
                        <h3>{item.title}</h3>
                        <Rate defaultValue={4} disabled />
                    </div>
                )
            })}
    </div>
</Col>
```

I want to make it default checked for a specific element of Radio Button Group

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow! Please, before asking a question [read this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with your question. That way you make it easy for other users to help you.

Comment: Please refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62912258/how-to-set-checked-with-radio-group-antd . I hope this might help.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution using with From

```
<Form.Item
   name="type"
   initialValue={1}
>
   <Radio.Group>
<Radio value={1}>off</Radio>
   </Radio.Group>
</Form.Item>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the prop defaultChecked to the specific index you want. An example for the first one would be:

```
<input defaultChecked={index === 0} />
```

In your case I would delete the checked value and add the defaultChecked.

```
<Radio.Group 
  options={uniqueRadioElements} 
  onChange={onCategorySelect} 
  value={selectedCategory} 
  optionType="button" 
  buttonStyle="solid" 
  className="select-category" 
  defaultChecked={index === 0} />
```

Comment: It causes me error Index is not defined. Can you help me please to explain what index should be like?
defaultChecked={uniqueRadioElements.indexOf === 0} /> like this ?

Comment: I am not seeing your whole code, so I am guessing that you are mapping your data, then add index in the map like: 

.map((item, index) => {}